# Aegir/OpenAtrium site crashing out of memory. Help?

Tags: aegir

Aegir/OpenAtrium site crashing out of memory. Help?

I have a 768 Linode on a CentOS LAMP running Drupal Aegir with just 3 Open Atrium sites, and about 10-20 concurrent users. At random times, it pukes Out of Memory kill. I can't figure out what's causing it. I'm not sure if i need to do some memory usage tweaking on my CentOS LAMP stack. I need to get this under control quickly or management is going to kill this project.. After a couple hours of a crash and burn OOM, here's some info. To my eye, it doesn't look like anything is wrong.

**First the ugly OOM output**

> ck:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? y es lowmem_reserve[]: 0 700 754 754 Normal free:5060kB min:3348kB low:4184kB high:5020kB active_anon:339984kB inactive_anon:340208kB act ive_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:1408kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:7172 88kB mlocked:1408kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:604kB shmem:28kB slab_reclaimable:7776kB slab_unr eclaimable:8448kB kernel_stack:1128kB pagetables:4404kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pa ges_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 428 428 HighMem free:116kB min:128kB low:192kB high:256kB active_anon:17624kB inactive_anon:17932kB active_f ile:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:3136kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:54868kB m locked:3136kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:3080kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimabl e:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:2 all_ unreclaimable? yes lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 DMA: 64kB 28kB 716kB 832kB 864kB 7128kB 5256kB 0512kB 01024kB 02048kB 04096kB = 3096kB Normal: 6394kB 2978kB 916kB 032kB 064kB 0128kB 0256kB 0512kB 01024kB 02048kB 04096kB = 50 76kB HighMem: 64kB 18kB 016kB 332kB 064kB 0128kB 0256kB 0512kB 01024kB 02048kB 0*4096kB = 128kB 56664 total pagecache pages 55697 pages in swap cache Swap cache stats: add 17100319, delete 17044622, find 7567477/9043262 Free swap = 0kB Total swap = 524284kB 198640 pages RAM 13826 pages HighMem 6639 pages reserved 14545 pages shared 188067 pages non-shared Out of memory: Kill process 3448 (httpd) score 41 or sacrifice child Killed process 3448 (httpd) total-vm:74716kB, anon-rss:26132kB, file-rss:1120kB

**Processes running**

```
[root@li21-298 ~]# ps aux
USER PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
root 1 0.0 0.0 2208 492 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 init [3]
root 2 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kthreadd]
root 3 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root 4 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kworker/0:0]
root 5 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kworker/u:0]
root 6 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [migration/0]
root 7 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [migration/1]
root 9 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root 10 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [migration/2]
root 12 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root 13 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [migration/3]
root 15 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root 16 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [cpuset]
root 17 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [khelper]
root 18 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root 19 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kworker/u:1]
root 21 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [xenwatch]
root 22 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [xenbus]
root 162 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [sync_supers]
root 164 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [bdi-default]
root 166 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [kblockd]
root 176 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kworker/3:1]
root 178 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [md]
root 262 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [rpciod]
root 263 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kworker/2:1]
root 275 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:04 [kswapd0]
root 276 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? SN 19:34 0:00 [ksmd]
root 277 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root 281 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [ecryptfs-kthr]
root 283 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [nfsiod]
root 284 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [cifsiod]
root 287 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [jfsIO]
root 288 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [jfsCommit]
root 289 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [jfsCommit]
root 290 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [jfsCommit]
root 291 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [jfsCommit]
root 292 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [jfsSync]
root 293 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [xfsalloc]
root 294 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [xfs_mru_cache]
root 295 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [xfslogd]
root 296 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [glock_workque]
root 297 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [delete_workqu]
root 298 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [gfs_recovery]
root 299 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [crypto]
root 862 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [khvcd]
root 976 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [kpsmoused]
root 1016 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< 19:34 0:00 [deferwq]
root 1019 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kjournald]
root 1023 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kworker/1:1]
root 1044 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [kauditd]
root 1077 0.0 0.0 2424 356 ? S<s 19:34 0:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root 2692 0.0 0.0 2452 40 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 /sbin/dhclient
root 2759 0.0 0.0 10624 420 ? S<sl 19:34 0:00 auditd
root 2761 0.0 0.0 11184 444 ? S<sl 19:34 0:00 /sbin/audispd
root 2781 0.0 0.0 1964 532 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 syslogd -m 0
root 2784 0.0 0.0 1808 288 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 klogd -x
named 2825 0.0 0.1 58936 1032 ? Ssl 19:34 0:00 /usr/sbin/named
dbus 2847 0.0 0.0 2896 504 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 dbus-daemon --s
root 2884 0.0 0.0 23272 524 ? Ssl 19:34 0:00 automount
root 2903 0.0 0.0 7256 632 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
ntp 2917 0.0 0.5 4548 4544 ? SLs 19:34 0:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp
root 2928 0.0 0.0 5344 160 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftp
root 2964 0.0 0.0 4676 572 ? S 19:34 0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bi
root 3018 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:34 0:00 [flush-202:0]
mysql 3057 7.9 1.7 126808 13296 ? Sl 19:34 14:23 /usr/libexec/my
root 3089 0.0 0.0 9372 696 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 sendmail: accep
smmsp 3097 0.0 0.0 8284 336 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 sendmail: Queue
root 3106 0.0 0.0 2044 152 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 gpm -m /dev/inp
root 3115 0.0 0.1 27820 1320 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root 3123 0.0 0.0 5380 552 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 crond
xfs 3141 0.0 0.0 3308 436 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 xfs -droppriv -
apache 3235 0.0 4.6 56924 35484 ? S 19:34 0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3239 0.0 5.7 72740 44192 ? S 19:34 0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3240 0.0 4.4 56636 34068 ? S 19:34 0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3241 0.0 4.1 52836 31660 ? S 19:34 0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3242 0.0 3.9 52800 30372 ? S 19:34 0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3243 0.0 4.0 52788 31428 ? S 19:34 0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3244 0.0 4.4 56924 34556 ? S 19:34 0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3245 0.0 4.5 57196 34828 ? S 19:34 0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd
root 3264 0.0 0.0 2408 180 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root 3279 0.0 0.2 26680 2192 ? SN 19:34 0:00 /usr/bin/python
root 3281 0.0 0.0 2704 536 ? SN 19:34 0:00 /usr/libexec/ga
root 3282 0.0 0.2 19420 1660 ? Ss 19:34 0:00 /usr/bin/perl /
apache 3491 0.0 3.3 52792 26060 ? S 19:35 0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3492 0.0 4.8 59656 37352 ? S 19:35 0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3493 0.0 4.5 56956 34564 ? S 19:35 0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache 3494 0.0 4.0 52788 31128 ? S 19:35 0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd
root 5343 0.0 0.0 3028 624 ? Ss 19:49 0:00 login -- root
root 5796 0.0 0.0 4808 604 hvc0 Ss 19:53 0:00 -bash
root 6054 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 19:55 0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root 6583 0.0 0.0 4320 352 hvc0 S+ 20:00 0:00 less
root 21913 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 21:53 0:00 [kworker/2:0]
root 22407 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 21:57 0:00 [kworker/3:0]
root 23117 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 22:02 0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root 24625 0.0 0.3 10264 2656 ? Ss 22:13 0:00 sshd: root@nott
root 24628 0.0 0.1 6692 1536 ? Ss 22:13 0:00 /usr/libexec/op
root 26703 0.0 0.3 10108 2932 ? Rs 22:28 0:00 sshd: root@pts/
root 26812 0.0 0.1 4812 1452 pts/0 Ss 22:29 0:00 -bash
root 27493 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S 22:34 0:00 [kworker/1:2]
root 27494 0.0 0.1 4400 932 pts/0 R+ 22:34 0:00 ps aux
```

**Free usage stats**

```
[root@li21-298 ~]# free -m
    total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 750 497 252 0 6 77
-/+ buffers/cache: 413 336
Swap: 511 87 424

[root@li21-298 ~]# free
    total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 768004 490708 277296 0 8680 79892
-/+ buffers/cache: 402136 365868
Swap: 524284 73136 451148
```

**List of running processes sorted by memory use**

```
ps -eo pmem,pcpu,rss,vsize,args | sort -k 1 -r | less

%MEM %CPU RSS VSZ COMMAND
4.9 0.0 38240 59656 /usr/sbin/httpd
4.7 0.0 36324 72740 /usr/sbin/httpd
4.6 0.0 35724 56940 /usr/sbin/httpd
4.6 0.0 35512 56924 /usr/sbin/httpd
4.2 0.0 32676 56924 /usr/sbin/httpd
4.2 0.0 32312 56380 /usr/sbin/httpd
3.8 0.0 29604 52800 /usr/sbin/httpd
3.7 0.0 29024 52792 /usr/sbin/httpd
3.7 0.0 28992 52788 /usr/sbin/httpd
3.7 0.0 28664 52788 /usr/sbin/httpd
1.8 7.8 13928 127624 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
0.9 0.0 7260 52836 /usr/sbin/httpd
0.5 0.0 4544 4548 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
0.3 0.0 2940 10108 sshd: root@pts/0
0.3 0.0 2680 26680 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-updatesd
0.2 0.0 2208 53236 /usr/sbin/httpd
0.2 0.0 1660 19420 /usr/bin/perl /usr/libexec/webmin/miniserv.pl /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
0.1 0.0 1460 4812 -bash 0.1 0.0 1320 27820 /usr/sbin/httpd :
```

**Type of MPM in use by Apache**

```
[root@li21-298 ~]# httpd -V | grep 'MPM'
Server MPM: Prefork
-D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
```

**Current settings in my httpd.conf file (/etc/httpd/httpd.conf)**

```
StartServers 8
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 20
ServerLimit 256
MaxClients 256
MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
```

**Current settings in mysql (located /etc/my.cnf)**

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=50M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what your memory limit in PHP actually is.

Answer (score 3):

Is this error displaying on the site's front-end? Or in your apache logs? And are you planning to run many more OpenAtrium instances?

If you're getting that error on the front-end, and aren't planning to run very many more OA installs, just up the memory_limit in php.ini, as it looks like you've actually got RAM to spare, and individual processes are maxing out the RAM they've been permitted. If you don't know which is the proper php.ini, check your Status Report.

If you're planning to run many more OA instances, I would increase the amount of RAM on the VPS. OA is heavy on memory.

If the site is just totally whiting out (aka WSOD), check your apache logs (though if that's the behavior, I'm guessing you already have) hopefully it'll give an idea of exactly what part of the system is maxing out the memory.

Comment: Thanks. This is my Linode console read-out. I didn't see anything out of the ordinary in my apache error log.I get the usual [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down.

Comment: I have 196M set in my PHP.ini file. As I mentioned, I have a 1GB VPS of RAM for 3 Atrium sites. Should be plenty. I'm wondering if PHP is making it explode somehow, or maybe I don't have my 1GB of RAM properly allocated.

Comment: I've had to up mine to 256 and 512MB just to get some of the heavier Drupal distributions installed. I've always been able to lower it back down to 128MB afterward, though.

I guess your next steps would be to see if there's any patterns to the "brown-outs", and do some low-level load testing yourself.